# Multicol results in superimposed text under some conditions. How can I avoid this?

Tags: multicol

I've run across a condition where the final page of a `multicols` environment winds up with overlapping text. As far as I can tell, the problem occurs when there are forced `\columnbreak`s on both the penultimate and the final page of the `multicols` *and* the columns on the penultimate page are short. If I fill the columns on the penultimate page, the problem does not occur.

The MWE illustrates the behavior:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[debugshow]{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\raggedbottom
\raggedcolumns
\setlength\columnsep{0.5in}
\setlength\columnseprule{.5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum[4]
% Uncommenting either this rule or the one in the next column
% balances the columns on the last page
%\rule{1pt}{350pt}

\columnbreak

\lipsum[4]

%\rule{1pt}{350pt}

\columnbreak

\lipsum[1]

\columnbreak

\lipsum[4]

\end{multicols}

And some concluding text
\end{document}
```

The resulting columns on the final page look like this:

[image: final columns of MWE]

The MWE is stripped down so much that my motivation for doing things this way might be obscure. Suffice it to say that I'm setting exam questions that require this layout, and given the other restrictions on how these questions are set up, the short columns and the `\columnbreak`s are unavoidable. Also note that I cannot use `multicols*` because I need one-column text below the `multicols` environment and on the same page. Similarly, I've looked at and rejected all of the parallel-column packages because they have restrictions that make them unusable for me.

I've tried to look at the log file to divine `multicol`'s reasoning here, but I can't follow why this occurs. My experiments with tweaking parameters like `finalcolumnbadness` haven't produced anything useful either.

The behavior that I would like to occur is that when I issue a `\columnbreak` on the final page of `multicols` text (and `\raggedcolumns` is in effect), `multicol` should trust I know what I'm doing and simply set the column height to the larger of the two columns. How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution uses the `colaction` option to determine whether to use `\columnbreak` or `\pagebreak` automatically.  It works by writing the column number in the AUX file, so will take (at least) two runs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[debugshow,colaction]{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\raggedbottom
\raggedcolumns
\setlength\columnsep{0.5in}
\setlength\columnseprule{.5pt}

\let\oldcolumnbreak=\columnbreak
\renewcommand{\columnbreak}{\docolaction{\pagebreak}{\oldcolumnbreak}{\oldcolumnbreak}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum[4]
% Uncommenting either this rule or the one in the next column
% balances the columns on the last page
%\rule{1pt}{350pt}

\columnbreak

\lipsum[4]

%\rule{1pt}{350pt}

\columnbreak

\lipsum[1]

\columnbreak

\lipsum[4]

\end{multicols}

And some concluding text
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my case, I always know which column I'm in, so `docolaction` isn't necessary to know which one to execute, but having the general case is very useful.

Answer (score 3):

That is an interesting scenario. Basically what happens in the following: the multicols body is so short that without the columnbreaks all would fit on a single page. Thus it reaches the end of the environment and starts balancing even through there are in fact 3 column breaks inside.

As a result the balancing fails and the recovery attempt is to cut a normal page and the remaining material is pushed back for reconsideration later. So far so good.

But after the first page is cut the balancing output routine is still in force (to balance the remaining material) after regathering it. Normally that would work sincely, but this time there is still one columnreak penalty in the material and as a columnbreak penalty is a forcing penalty, the re-gathering of material for the OR stops at that point and balances only the material up to this point.

That is then pushed back (as a single box of full page width) as if it was the end of the multicols environment, but as it isn't really the whole amount of material the code now collects the rest and does another balancing.

As the first balancing produced a box of full width (which is now ending up in the st column of the second balancing) it overprints part of the second column ands that is what one sees.

It is not easy to fix as the code for `\columnbreak` was never intended to be use as a general marker to split of all columns but only to help multicols along if it doesn't find the right breakpoint, which is why I never considered the case of ending up with more columnbreak than valid in the balancing. As a result I had to change the overall logic a lot (hopefully correctly).

So please try out the following to see if it works in your real documents (it doesn't with the examples I tried and you MWE).

```
\usepackage[balancingshow]{multicol}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\endmulticols
  {\penalty\z@
   \output{\balance@columns@out}%
   \eject}
  {\penalty-\@Mvi}
  {\typeout{Success patching}}{\ERROR}


\patchcmd\speci@ls
  {\else \PackageWarningNoLine{multicol}}
  {\else
      \ifnum\outputpenalty = -\@Mvi
        \mult@info\@ne{End penalty of multicols seen}%
        \outputpenalty\@M 
        \balance@columns@out
    \else \PackageWarningNoLine{multicol}}
  {\typeout{Success patching}}{\ERROR}

\patchcmd\speci@ls
  {\else \@doclearpage \fi}
  {\fi \else \@doclearpage \fi}
  {\typeout{Success patching}}{\ERROR}

\patchcmd\balance@columns@out
  {\unvbox\mult@box}
  {\unvbox\mult@box \penalty-\@Mvi}
  {\typeout{Success patching}}{\ERROR}

\mathchardef\@Mvi=10006
\makeatother
```

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly in my production document (although so does John's solution of simply substituting `\pagebreak` at the relevant points. (And I think you mean it _does_ work with the MWE, etc.)

Comment: Of course that would work too, because then the balancing will not end up with too many \columnbreak's inside, but that only fixes the symptoms not the actual issue :-)

Comment: @KarlHagen actually the change as initially written kills `multicols*` so not that perfect  (I'll update the code in my answer to account for that). The final version will appear in the next release of `multicol`.